# Web.config mass 301 redirect old news page to a slightly different Urls

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I need to redirect a bunch of news articles to a different url format using web.config.

For example, this Url:

```
https://www.example.com/footer/press-resources/press-releases/press-release-detail/abcd-press-release-item
```

Should be redirected to this Url:

```
https://www.example.com/about/press-releases/press-release-detail/abcd-press-release-item
```

In this example, as you can see this portion of the Url is staying intact **/press-release-detail/abcd-press-release-item** but everything else before this should be redirected. The only dynamic part of the Url is the article's title which is at the end of the Url, in this case: **abcd-press-release-item**

I have about 300 items, obviously redirecting them one by one is going to take some time.  Is there a way to rule them all out and mass redirect the old Urls to the new ones?

This is a Windows/IIS server with a .NET CMS and a web.config file.
I tried this rule and it didn't work for me:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^https://www.example.com/footer/press-resources/press-releases/press-release-detail\$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/about/press-releases/press-release-detail" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this URL Rewrite rule:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(footer)/(press-resources)(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/about{R:3}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm :) thank you! Do you mind describing what exactly happened here?